# Powershell - Pasar contenido desde csv a query SQL

Tags: powershell

necesito de su ayuda con lo siguiente:

Tengo un archivo .csv que contiene dos columnas y puede contener varias filas, dependiendo de los datos que se generen en él

```
numero   descripcion
------   ------------
1        uno
2        dos
3        tres
```

lo que hago para leerlo es con cmdlet import-cdv de esta forma: `$csv=import-csv -path rutadelarchivo.csv`

luego, lo paso a una variable `$v=$csv` y esto lo llevo a un for para que formatee el número con un largo definido `for ($u=0; $u -lt $v.lenght; $u++) $i =$v[$u];`

y finalmente paso el dato a la conexión para que lo ponga en un select:

```
$qry= `"SELECT " + i.ToString() + "AS numero" FROM tabla`
```

Hasta acá todo bien, me genera la consulta y exporta los resultados a un csv diferente por cada linea de la columna "numero" del archivo csv.

El problema ocurre cuando es un solo valor el que trae el csv de origen, por ejemplo '201', el cual "descompone" y genera tres consultas con cada número: una con 2, otra con 0 y otra con 1.

No sé como solucionarlo. Agradecería su ayuda

Comment: Esto no se refiere a tu problema, pero quiero llamarte la atención a una función que escribí en powershell para generar SQL, entre otros, en base a un patrón y un archivo csv.  Se llama Expand-Csv y lo puedes ver en http://github.com/dcressey/Expand-Csv  y tambi[en bajarlo.  El archivo Results.txt tiene dos muestras del empleo de esta función, y uno de ellos genera comandos GRANT en SQL.  Te puede ser útil.